# How to find the max length of an array from a set of documents present in a collection in MongoDB?

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo, pymongo-3.x, flask-pymongo

I have **'n'** number of documents present inside a collection in MongoDB.
Structure of those documents is as follows:

```
{
    "_id": "...",
    "submissions": [{...}, ...]
}
```

I want to find the document which has the highest number of submissions out of all the documents present.
Is there any Mongo find/aggregation query which can do the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think any straight way to achieve this,

You can try below aggregation query,

- `$addFields` to add new field `totalSubmissions` to get total elements in `submissions` array
- `$sort` by `totalSubmissions` in descending order
- `$limit` to select single document

```
collection.aggregate([
  { $addFields: { totalSubmissions: { $size: "$submissions" } } },
  { $sort: { totalSubmissions: -1 } },
  { $limit: 1 }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/VKrD3i51_Rr)